# How would I find the limit of this recursive sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, parametric, centroid

### The Question

> $$x_n(c)=\frac{\int_{1}^{c} x_{n-1}(b)y_{n-1}(b)db}{\int_{1}^{c} y_{n-1}(b)x_{n-1}(b)'db}, x_1(c)=\frac{\int_{1}^{c} xf(x)dx}{\int_{1}^{c} f(x)dx} $$
>
> $$y_n(c)=\frac{\int_{1}^{c} y_{n-1}(b)^2db}{\int_{1}^{c} y_{n-1}(b)x_{n-1}(b)'db}, y_1(c)=\frac{\int_{1}^{c} f(x)^2dx}{2\int_{1}^{c} f(x)dx} $$

### My Understanding

So say we wanted to find the centroid of the region bounded by the curve $y=f(x)$, $y=0$, $x=1$, and $x=b$. The parametric function obtained would give the path that the centroid "travels" as $b$ goes from 1 to infinity. We could then find the centroid of the region bounded by that curve, $y=0$, $x=1$, and $x = b$. From this, you get a sequence of functions and I was wondering if/when does that sequence converge. I found a recursive sequence for the nth set of parametric equations but I don't know how to get the limit as n goes to infinity from there. I think if we start from functions like $y=\frac{1}{x}$, the sequence will converge but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: sorry about that. It should be good now

Comment: Do you have a particular curve in mind? I imagine the general case will probably be quite a complicated formula.

Comment: i started tackling this question with y=1/x. But by the second term of the sequence, the integrands aren't elementary. So I guess for now, any function that converges to 0 as x approaches infinity would be interesting to look at.

Comment: actually scratch that. Those might just converge to y=0. Instead I think something like y=x^2 since the integrals in its sequence should be easy to compute.